# How to model noncopyable in Rational Rhapsody 8.0.1

Tags: c++, rhapsody

I want to make a class in my Rhapsody model non-copyable, but

- don't have the boost library available (from which I would just derive)
- nor can I use the C++11 way of disabling the default generated copy ctor and copy assignment op (because I would need to manipulate the function signature, which AFAIK is not directly possible)

=> so I am doing it the old fascioned way.

**What I need from Rhapsody:**

In this context, I want to generate only a declaration for copy ctor and copy assignment op - I don't need the implementation.
Is this even possible?

**Things that I considered:**

- I haven't found any helpful property yet.
- Mapping only the specification of a member function to a file object won't prevent Rhapsody from generating the empty function body into an implicitly created file object (that I don't need nor want).

Comment: I actually found a way of only generating the specification code (which was what I wanted :-)):

Property *CG::Operation::Generate* has to be set to "_Specification_". By default, it will be set to "_Full_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a stereotype approach:

1. Create a `NonCopyable` base class, as, for example, described by @Dennis.
2. Create a stereotype, you can, for example, name it `<<non-copyable>>`.

   a) Set the stereotype property `CPP_CG::Class::AdditionalBaseClasses` to `NonCopyable` (the name of the base class created above).

   b) Make the stereotype applicable to classes.
3. Finally, add the `<<non-copyable>>` stereotype to all classes that shall be non copyable.

Comment: I will try this next week, as I believe this might be the cleanest solution in regard to Rhapsody.

I'm waiting a bit with marking this answer as the correct one a bit longer - I want to leave a little room for other suggestions (in case someone knows a way to generate just specification, not implementation, of a function)

Comment: this basically works, _but_ when you employ the nonCopyable-stereotype, the inheritance relationship is implicetly private, because no inheritance type is specified (public, private, protected)

Answer (score 0):

Write a private copy ctor and opertor:

```
class NonCopy {
    // These private versions of the copy constructor 
    // and operator will signal to the compiler to 
    // prevent automatic generation.
    NonCopy(const NonCopy& other);
    const NonCopy& operator=(const NonCopy& other);
public:
    // Your public ctors
    NonCopy(int a);
}
```

You can look at the [boost version of the non-copyable interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/core/noncopyable.hpp) for a more complete example.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14329808)

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: @Garf365 - I've edited for more context as Toby suggested, but you are suggesting that I am not answering the question. From my reading he wants a class that is non-copyable. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: ok, to make it clear: I know how to implement non-copyable per se. I do want get around having to write the empty function bodies, however.

Also, the operator= from the example above will probably not compile, because nothing is returned. My desire is to be able to generate this single line of code:

`const NonCopy& operator=(const NonCopy& other);`

Comment: Write it once and inherit from it.

Comment: That may solve the immediate problem but it still doesn't answer my question: Can I somehow get Rhapsody to just generate a function declaration?

If the answer is "no", that's ok, too. Then I guess implementing it once and inheriting is ok.

Comment: Ah, sorry. In that case, yes I can see how my answer does not answer that!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done (at least in Rhapsody 8.2.0) using a combination of properties of the constructor. First, set the `CG::Operation::Generate` property to `Specification`, then set the `CPP_CG::Operation::PostDeclarationModifier` to `= delete`. (Both of these are set at the constructor level). This ensures that no function body is created, and also allows usage of the `delete` keyword via modification of the function signature.

I have not found a way to write this in code and have Rhapsody interpret it correctly while roundtripping, though.